# Matching CF convention coordinates systems to Cartopy's

Tags: cartopy

I am a newby with Cartopy, so ....

How can you transform the CF-convention metadata describing the coordinate systems of the data (from your NetCDF file) to a Cartopy's CRS object ?

I was expecting that the API reference would include, in the "input/output capability" section, some entry providing a method for returning, from the [CF-compliant metadata section](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.8/cf-conventions.html#coordinate-system) of a NetCDF file (or equivalent in memory structure), a corresponding CRS object, to be used as the `transform` parameter of Cartopy's high level functions

Comment: I use Iris, which works it out for me, e.g.  https://scitools-iris.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/gallery/general/plot_polar_stereo.html

Comment: Thanks Ruth. Unfortunately, my first trial at opening a file with Iris was unsuccessful, and I am furthermore deeply embarked with cartopy ...